# How to use a multi-element string for a IN sql query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is it possible to use the input from one field of the database for another query in combination with the `IN` statement. The point is that in the sting, I use for `IN`, contains several by comma separated values:

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM refPlant 
  WHERE id IN (SELECT cover 
               FROM meta_characteristic 
               WHERE id = 2);
```

the string of the subquery is: `1735,1736,1737,1738,1739,1740,1741,1742,1743,1744`

The query above give me only the first element of the string. But when I put the string directly in the query, I get all the ten elements:

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM refPlant 
  WHERE id IN (735,1736,1737,1738,1739,1740,1741,1742,1743,1744);
```

Is it possible to have all ten elements and not only one with query like the first one.

My sql version is 10.1.16-MariaDB

Comment: you can use `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: @vkp thx it works. why you post the answer as comment and not as answer? i can not mark the question solved.

Comment: This is an example of why not to use commalists of values.

Comment: @RickJames you mean is in general not a good idea to do...you can give some more explanations?

Comment: Filling a cell with an array of values is a common theme on this forum -- it is repeatedly criticized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in the `join` condition.

```
SELECT r.id, r.name 
FROM refPlant r 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM meta_characteristic m WHERE id=2) m 
ON FIND_IN_SET(r.id,m.cover) > 0
```

Comment: can you have a look on my anther below and tell me if there is a difference between the both solutions.

Comment: from what was described in the question, i see no difference. your answer should work too, if you are sure only one value is returned for the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a sub-query as in the first code snippet you will get a filter for each row returned from it. It will not work when it returns as a single string field.

Comment: thy but I can not run a query on the ids i like to select, because they are chosen by the user.

Comment: What is the structure of the meta_charateristic table?

Comment: meta_characteristic have 5 columns and 3 rows, when testing is over it have between 100 and 1000 rows. the column `cover` is a string which contains comma separated ID of another table (refPlant) with about 20.000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM refPlant 
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (SELECT cover 
               FROM meta_charateristic 
               WHERE id = 2));
```